# My ImmutableList Collector is not working?

Tags: java, lambda, java-8, guava, java-stream

I am trying to build a Java 8 Collector implementation for Guava's ImmutableList. But I keep getting weird null pointer errors. What is wrong with my collector?

> java.lang.NullPointerException    at
>   java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.collect(Unknown Source)    at
>   com.swa.rm.common.test.TestLauncher.main(TestLauncher.java:50)

is the error I recieve when I try to run this code...

> ImmutableList.of(1,5,2,7,8,2,4)
>                         .stream().filter(i -> i % 2 == 0)
>                         .collect(new ImmutableListCollector())
>                         .forEach(i -> System.out.println(i));

which invokes this collector

```
package com.swa.rm.common.stream;

import java.util.EnumSet;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.function.BiConsumer;
import java.util.function.BinaryOperator;
import java.util.function.Function;
import java.util.function.Supplier;
import java.util.stream.Collector;

import com.google.common.collect.ImmutableList;

public class ImmutableListCollector<T> implements Collector<T, ImmutableList.Builder<T>, ImmutableList<T>> {

 @Override
 public Supplier<ImmutableList.Builder<T>> supplier() {
  return ImmutableList::builder;
 } 

 @Override
 public BiConsumer<ImmutableList.Builder<T>, T> accumulator() {
  return (builder, t) -> builder.add(t);
 }

 @Override
 public BinaryOperator<ImmutableList.Builder<T>>  combiner() {
  return (left, right) -> { 
   left.addAll(right.build());
   return left;
  };
 }

 @Override
 public Function<ImmutableList.Builder<T>, ImmutableList<T>> finisher() {
  return null;
 }

 @Override
 public Set<Characteristics> characteristics() {
  return EnumSet.of(Characteristics.UNORDERED);
 }

}
```

UPDATE:: Here is the final implementation and it seems to work now.

```
import java.util.EnumSet;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.function.BiConsumer;
import java.util.function.BinaryOperator;
import java.util.function.Function;
import java.util.function.Supplier;
import java.util.stream.Collector;

import com.google.common.collect.ImmutableList;

public class ImmutableListCollector<T> implements Collector<T, ImmutableList.Builder<T>, ImmutableList<T>> {


         @Override
         public Supplier<ImmutableList.Builder<T>> supplier() {
          return (() -> ImmutableList.builder());
         } 

         @Override
         public BiConsumer<ImmutableList.Builder<T>, T> accumulator() {
          return (builder, t) -> builder.add(t);
         }

         @Override
         public BinaryOperator<ImmutableList.Builder<T>>  combiner() {
          return (left, right) -> { 
           left.addAll(right.build());
           return left;
          };
         }

         @Override
         public Function<ImmutableList.Builder<T>, ImmutableList<T>> finisher() {
             return (b -> builder.build());
         }

         @Override
         public Set<Characteristics> characteristics() {
          return EnumSet.of(Characteristics.UNORDERED);
         }

}
```

Comment: FYI, your final implementation looks incorrect since its `supplier()` returns the same `ImmutableList.Builder` instance rather than creating a new one each time. There are multiple issues with doing that, including: A) the builder could be added to from multiple threads at the same time, when it isn't thread safe; B) the `combiner()` will be adding all of the builder's elements to the builder itself; C) the `Collector` itself is stateful and can't be reused.

Comment: Yes I actually figured that out and I switched the supplier over to provide a new builder instance each time, and rid the one hanging around on top as a property. I'll update the code above to reflect this later today.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `finisher()` function is `null`; I'm not sure what you expected.

Comment: Oops, well now I feel sheepish. I can't believe I overlooked that.